# Constructing realizations of Hilberts weak Nullstellensatz?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we are given a set of $m$ polynomials $f_1,f_2,...,f_m$ in $n$ variables $z_1,...,z_n$ on an algebraically closed field, i.e. $\mathbb{C}^n[z_1,...,z_n]$. Furthermore, suppose that the set of polynomials does not share any common zeros, such that due to Hilberts weak Nullstellensatz a solution to the following equation must exist

$$Q_1 f_1 + Q_2 f_2+...+Q_m f_m=1$$

Where the $Q_i$ are certain polynomials in $\mathbb{C}^n[z_1,...,z_n]$. There exist general [upper bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz#Effective_Nullstellensatz) on the degrees of polynomials $Q_i$. However, what I am interested in is whether there exist explicit construction methods for the $Q_i$ once an example set of $f_i$ is given? Is there a general procedure to obtain the $Q_i$? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What has the existence of a linear combination of $1$ to do with the weak Nullstellensatz?

Comment: @k.stm The weak Nullstellensatz can be defined as an existence criterium  in this manner. It is nicely outlined i.e. in https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/hilberts-nullstellensatz/

Comment: Ok, but you literally wrote “suppose that the set of polynomials does not span a proper ideal”, which implies they span all of $ℂ[z_1, …, z_n]$, which in turn implies that $1$ is in their span which exactly says that there is a linear combination of $1$ using $f_1, …, f_m$ in the manner you stated. Don’t need any Nullstellensatz here, just unpacking definitions. Maybe you want to say “suppose that the set of polynomials doesn’t share a common zero”? Or just leave out the “due to weak Nullstellensatz” part.

Comment: @k.stm You are right, the set of polynomials not sharing the same zero is a sufficient property for what I'd like to know. I will edit the question and change it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be done with Gröbner bases. I [had a very similar question once](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132101/ideal-membership-without-certificate). An [implementation can be found in sage](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/multi_polynomial_element.html#sage.rings.polynomial.multi_polynomial_element.MPolynomial_polydict.lift), which uses [the lift method from singular](http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-0-2/sing_513.htm).

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with Macaulay2 by using the // operator (line i13 below):

```
i7 : S=QQ[x,y]

o7 = S

o7 : PolynomialRing

i12 : id2=ideal(y-x^2,x-2, y-5)

                2
o12 = ideal (- x  + y, x - 2, y - 5)

o12 : Ideal of S

i13 : 1 // gens id2

o13 = {2} | 1   |
      {1} | x+2 |
      {1} | -1  |

              3       1
o13 : Matrix S  <--- S
```